# Puppet - noop all resources in a scope

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to noop all resources in a scope?
I want to be able to mark an entire module as noop under certain situations.

I know I can use default syntax to set this up on a resource type basis:

```
Package { noop => true }
Service { noop => true }
```

However, I would have to do this for all types used, which seems fragile.  Is there any way to accomplish the same thing for all resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/trlinkin/noop) for just what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no means to do this directly.

You can use the `--tags` parameter to limit the set of applied resources to those that have at least one of the specified tags. This cannot satisfy your requirements in all situations, but does allow some distinct tests and applications.

Comment: I don't really want to control this from the command line, but directly within the module itself.  It doesn't look like I can filter by tags that way.